# @Html.ActionLink one works and one does not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.actionlink

I have two @Html.ActionLink's one works and one does not and I cannot figure out why?

They are both within the same controller: StoreController and both call ActionResults within different controllers, this is the one that works and calls the Index function within the Director Class:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
    <h2>@item.Title</h2>
    </li>
    <li class = "lihead">
    Directed by 
    @Html.ActionLink((string)item.Director.Name, "Index", "Director", new { searchString = item.Director.Name }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
    <i>@item.Synopsis</i>
    </li> 
    <li class = "lihead">
    Price per ticket £
    @item.Price
    </li>        
}
```

This is the one that does not work:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        @Html.ActionLink("Check Availability", "CheckAvail", "Booking", new { id = item.ShowId })
```

}

This one calls within the StoreController when I want it to call the CheckAvail function within the BookingController. However it does work when I amend it as so:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        @Html.ActionLink("Check Availability", "CheckAvail", "Booking")}
```

But I need it to take through the ShowId to the function???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Availability", "CheckAvail", "Booking", new { @id = item.ShowId },null)
```

It is using this overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx

the last parameter is the HTML attribute. If you have some HTML atribute to pass, you pass it there instead of null

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Availability", "CheckAvail", "Booking", new { @id = item.ShowId },new { @class="myCssClass"} )
```

Comment: Your answer is giving the same error as mine: The name item does not exist in the current context?

Comment: @Spangle : Are you getting an error ? do you have a custom route definition than the default one ?

Comment: Your answer is correct I had changed my page some may times just needed some tweaking!